# Acces to file path denied using WaveFileReader(NAudio) in uwp

Tags: c#, audio, merge, uwp, concatenation

Trying to combine audio files into one using the following method:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = null;
try
{
    foreach (string sourceFile in sourceFiles)
    {
        WaveFileReader reader=null;
        
        using ( reader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFile))
        {
        if (waveFileWriter == null)
        {
            // first time in create new Writer
            waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputFile, reader.WaveFormat);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!reader.WaveFormat.Equals(waveFileWriter.WaveFormat))
            {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't concatenate WAV Files that don't share the same format");
            }
        }

        int read;
        while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            waveFileWriter.WriteData(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    if (waveFileWriter != null)
    {
        waveFileWriter.Dispose();
    }
}
```

- **outputFile**: name of combined file;
- **sourceFiles**: string list of paths to audio files;

When using the method, i get the following exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Access to the path 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Gebura battle_541f3d9f-a4b9-4491-b6b6-75ede45e1748.wav' is denied."

I tried running visual studio as administrator, that didn't work. What should I do, to make it work?

Comment: shift the file to within the application dir

Comment: Tried, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone runs into the same issue i've kinda found a solution
First off, for some reason UWP allows you to create files only in setted directories (ApplicationData.Current contains allowed folders). You can also read and redact files, but only in KnownFolders folders or ApplicatioData.Current ones. So if you need to create a file do it in thoose folders and move them using StorageFile.MoveAsync(StorageFolder destinationFolderPath); For some reason you can move files from thoose folders to other folders
Example of moving some files:

```
 try
            {
                StorageFile WhereTo = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync("SavingFolderAudioCutter.txt"); // this file contains a path to a folder
                string oof = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(WhereTo); //getting a path
                StorageFolder dest = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(oof); //setting StorageFolder path from a string 
                string path = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path + $@"\{uniqueName}.wav"; // setting a name for a moved file
                StorageFile FromWhere = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path); // Original file location
             
                    await FromWhere.MoveAsync(dest);
                
                UtilityFunctions.DeleteFilesFromDir(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path); // Deleting files from a temporary folder
                FileList.Items.Clear();
            }
           catch
            {
                MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("The folder is read-only or incorrect choosen path");

                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code of [WaveFileReader](https://github.com/SjB/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveStreams/WaveFileReader.cs) and it is using `File.OpenRead` method to open the file via path. It is not allowed to use IO/File APIs with Path in UWP app because UWP apps are isolated in the sandbox. This is the reason for this behavior. If you want to use this API in UWP apps, you might need to contact the author of NAudio and change the source code of `WaveFileReader`.

Comment: That's a nice bit of info, but I managed to solve my problem in the end. Still, u got my thanks

Comment: @Creeprus Glad to hear that. You could post your solution here and mark it as answer. This might help others who are facing the same issue.